Springboot 3 Micrometer tracing Issue
We are using Springboot 3.1.4 and i have been trying to leverage the Micrometer based approach for distrubted tracing of the application. I have included the right build.gradle dependencies but the traces are only working for the health checkpoints and nothing else. Looking deeper I noticed a strange behavior. There are 2 flows i tested:
Flow 1 -> REST call to service 1 -> JMS Publish to service 2 method
Flow 2 -> REST call to service 2 method
In both cases, the incoming service received a PropagatedSpan with traceFlags=00. In this case no traces/spans got captured/sent.
({opentelemetry-trace-span-key=PropagatedSpan{ImmutableSpanContext{traceId=a2ea0716a45d02a490d7cef097acdb9a, spanId=adb8f982d4294b13, traceFlags=00, traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false, valid=true}}, opentelemetry-baggage-key={}, otelTraceContext=ImmutableSpanContext{traceId=a2ea0716a45d02a490d7cef097acdb9a, spanId=adb8f982d4294b13, traceFlags=00, traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false, valid=true}})
However, when the service 2 received the request from service 1 in Flow 1, it received the span as a SDKSpan with traceFlags=01. When this happens, i see the traces/spans captured for the service 2 (not service 1).
({opentelemetry-baggage-key={}, opentelemetry-trace-span-key=SdkSpan{traceId=c92ee058c19d5288d6cc72d2bb9c2a3b, spanId=5797df5b5620f02d, parentSpanContext=ImmutableSpanContext{traceId=00000000000000000000000000000000, spanId=0000000000000000, traceFlags=00, traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false, valid=false}, name=, kind=SERVER, attributes=null, status=ImmutableStatusData{statusCode=UNSET, description=}, totalRecordedEvents=0, totalRecordedLinks=0, startEpochNanos=1727214899985765169, endEpochNanos=0}, otelTraceContext=ImmutableSpanContext{traceId=c92ee058c19d5288d6cc72d2bb9c2a3b, spanId=5797df5b5620f02d, traceFlags=01, traceState=ArrayBasedTraceState{entries=[]}, remote=false, valid=true}}
Is there a way i can make the incoming trace/span to leverage SDKSpan instead of PropagatedSpan, which seems to block even the custom spans i created?
Any other way to address this issue? Thank you in advance!
SG

Not sure what happened to the comments on this question. Finally, i found a way to address this. The issue was happening due to x-b3-sampled set to 0. And this was due to the tracing protocol being http and i had b3 as one of the tracing propagation type (in addition to w3c). i have since removed the b3 and now it's all working fine. As for the grpc, it will work but will require a custom otlpGrpcSpanExporter bean defined
